# How are Django custom widget assets retrieved by the browser?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been reading this part of the django documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition
and this raised a question for me.

I think in order for the animations and actions js files to be used by the browser they have to be referenced in a script html tag.

As defining js assets in the form widget, like shown in the documentation, does not add any  tag in the html template I do not understand how these files will be retrieved by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this question in parts.

**How are the files retrieved**

Remember the STATICFILES_DIRS setting in your settings.py? My take will be that Django, while rendering your files through the form, will automatically append that in front of your file name and then include it in your template (more on the next part).

In other words, Django does this the same way how it handles static files in your templates, but you don't have to manually load the tags.

**Does not add any tag**

Have you ever noticed that, while you were working with forms, all you type are CharFields and whatever and Django automatically loads those into the body tag? I believe Django will automatically do that (which the keyword arguments can be processed differently than the rest of your form) but loads into the script tag.